# Why my change function doesnt work in jquerymobile when Im using multiple selectmenu

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

```
<select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu = false multiple=true>
<option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
<option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
</select>

$("#select-choice-1").selectmenu({
    change: function() {
        DataObj.GetJson(DataObj.GetRequestUrl("InitData","sessionKey="+ DataObj.sessionKey),"InitData");
    }
});
```

That's all my code about select change above.But It doesnt work when I changed the selected menu.I got no idea how it happened

Comment: Now,I've already finished the project.Still I can't understand why I coundn't fire the event using change function.Must the event binded in the document.ready() nor it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#select-choice-1").selectmenu();
$("#select-choice-1").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
        DataObj.GetJson(DataObj.GetRequestUrl("InitData","sessionKey="+ DataObj.sessionKey),"InitData");
});
```

Comment: I tried this,but it didnt work.Fire bug said $("#select-choice-1").selectmenu is not a function.Im using jquery 1.64,will it work in jquery 1.7?

Comment: I am using latest jQueryMobile js from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js)

Comment: this still doesnt work。I used the onchange event for DOM instead and it works，what was the matter?